# Cannot link against boost

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I try to build a project against boost. During linking part, I get several errors like this one:

```
2>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t & __cdecl boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::instance(void)" (?instance@unit_test_log_t@unit_test@boost@@SAAEAV123@XZ)
...
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::unit_test::master_test_suite_t & __cdecl boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite(void)" (?master_test_suite@framework@unit_test@boost@@YAAEAVmaster_test_suite_t@23@XZ) referenced in function "class boost::unit_test::test_suite * __cdecl init_unit_test_suite(int,char * * const)" (?init_unit_test_suite@@YAPEAVtest_suite@unit_test@boost@@HQEAPEAD@Z)
```

I do not know why this happens. I had boost version 1.71 and updated it to boost version 1.73. With boost 1.71 I could build the project without problems but after update I got these errors. The path to headers and library files are the same. I just deleted old headers and library files and replaced them with new files.

#### How I build boost

When I am building boost, I do it with commands like this one (in a batch script):

```
call bootstrap.bat

:: ...

call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

:: ...

b2 --build-type=complete -a toolset=msvc variant=debug threading=multi link=static address-model=64 -sBZIP_SOURCE="path\to\bzip2"  -sICU_PATH="path\to\icu" include="path\to\icu\include" -sZLIB_INCLUDE="path\to\zlib\include" -sZLIB_LIBPATH="path\to\zlib\lib64" -sZLIB_SOURCE="path\to\zlib\src"

:: ...

b2 --build-type=complete -a toolset=msvc variant=release threading=multi link=static address-model=64 -sBZIP_SOURCE="path\to\bzip2"  -sICU_PATH="path\to\icu" include="path\to\icu\include" -sZLIB_INCLUDE="path\to\zlib\include" -sZLIB_LIBPATH="path\to\zlib\lib64"  -sZLIB_SOURCE="path\to\zlib\src"
```

I am doing the same in four different versions: static/dynamic and release/debug. After build was finished I looked at the output of the build and I couldn't find any error. I searched for the word 'error' in the output and couldn't find anything. Also, looking at the output, it seems that boost is builing everything:

```
- atomic                   : building
- chrono                   : building
- container                : building
- context                  : building
- contract                 : building
- coroutine                : building
- date_time                : building
- exception                : building
- fiber                    : building
- filesystem               : building
- graph                    : building
- graph_parallel           : building
- headers                  : building
- iostreams                : building
- locale                   : building
- log                      : building
- math                     : building
- mpi                      : building
- nowide                   : building
- program_options          : building
- python                   : building
- random                   : building
- regex                    : building
- serialization            : building
- stacktrace               : building
- system                   : building
- test                     : building
- thread                   : building
- timer                    : building
- type_erasure             : building
- wave                     : building
```

So, for me this looks good to me, but somehow the linker is missing here something.

#### Edit

In the vcxproj file there are following settings regarding boost

```
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>...;path\to\boost\include;...;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
 ...
    </ClCompile>
 ...

    <Link>
     <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>...;path\to\boost\lib64;...;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
...
    </Link>
```

For `Release|x64` the preprocessor definition `BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE` is active.

#### Edit 2

To the header file `boost\config\user.hpp` I added this line to get more information

```
#define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC
```

and then I compiled my project again. I saw lines like these in the output

```
Line 13: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 14: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 15: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 16: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 17: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 18: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_regex-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 184: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 185: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 186: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 187: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 197: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 198: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 216: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_random-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 226: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_timer-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 227: 1>Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 323: 2>Linking to lib file: libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 324: 2>Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 325: 2>Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 326: 2>Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
Line 369: 2>Linking to lib file: libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib
```

The only thing I am missing here is `libboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib` because all `unresolved external symbol` errors are pointing somehow to test framework of boost. But `libboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib` is in the same directory as all the other libboost*.lib files.

Comment: what is the build command/settings for your project that includes boost?

Comment: @UnforeseenPrincess Could you be more precise ?

Comment: Are you `#include`ing `boost/test/unit_test.hpp`?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes. Please note that I can build the project with boost 1.71 without changing a single line of code, but after update to boost 1.73 I get this error

Comment: You also have to define BOOST_TEST_MAIN or BOOST_TEST_MODULE before including this file, I think they have changed that recently.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. ` This looks promising. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: The requirement to define one of those is in the documentation of boost::test. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_module_macro.html The change log is on github :)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you for your help. Your hints regarding `BOOST_TEST_MODULE ` helped to solve this problem.